# Logical functions with no arguments

Tags: evaluation, logic

I am trying to understand how logical functions are evaluated if no arguments are passed to them.

```
{Or[], Nor[], And[], Nand[], Xor[], Xnor[]}
```

> {False, True, True, False, False, True}

I tried `Trace` but it didn't offer many clues. Mathematica (12.2.0 on Win7-x64) evaluates these expressions without any messages.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you have a look in the Properties and relations section you will see that it zero-argument evaluates to `False`.  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or.html

Comment: Similar situation in Java https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

Comment: Perhaps this is the way they are supposed to be constructed based on theoretical coding principles? Sorry for the triple comment...I am horrible

Comment: These are simply the trivial cases for these functions. `And`, for example, is `True` unless one of it's arguments is `False`. The zero-argument case is just an extension of that.

Comment: One sees similar behavior with `Plus` and `Times` (where it might be more obviously plausible). Symbols with the `OneIdentity` attribute will, when given an empty argument list, evaluate to their respective identity elements.

Comment: a similar behavior: v8 js will calculate Math.min() to Infinity. use f12's console, type `Math.min()` to see it :)

Answer (score 6):

I am pretty sure that Syed figured out the question by now, but for future visitors I thought it a good idea to write something.

> 1. Why does `Or[]` return `False`?

From the [**`docs`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or.html) we read

***It evaluates its arguments in order, giving True immediately if any of them are True, and False if they are all False.***

which is another way of saying that it returns `True` if any or all of its arguments is true and `False` otherwise.

> 2. Why does `Nor[]` return `True`?

The easiest way to realize this -I think- is again to have a look at the [**`documentation`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nor.html?v=13.2) where we find that it is equivalent to `Not[Or[]]`. So, `Not[False]` is `True`.

> 3. Why does `And[]` return `True`?

Well, again this can be seen directly from the [**`docs`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/And.html) and also from the comment by @Sjoerd Smit.

It evaluates to `False` if any of its arguments are false, and to `True` otherwise.

> 4. Why does `Nand[]` return `False`?

Similar to the explanation of `Nor` in this case. `Nand[]` is equivalent to `Not[And[]]` and hence `Not[True]` which is `False`.

> 5. Why does `Xor[]` return `False`?

Well, it has to evaluate all of its argument and yields `True` if an odd number of them is `True` and `False` otherwise. Since, we do not have an odd number of `True` statements, it returns `False`

> 6. Why does `Xnor[]` return `True`?

`Xnor[]` is equivalent to `Not[Xor[]]`

Comment: Thanks for the write up.

Comment: @Syed if you want to add more to it, let me know and I will turn it into a wiki :-)

Comment: It seems that in your description of `Nor` `True` and `False` should be reversed.

Comment: @yarchik yes, of course you are right. thanks for spotting this :-)

Answer (score 3):

The answer of @bmf is perfect, but I would like to bring some arguments that allow us to better remember the results. It also shows a connection to other MA functions.

The `Xor` function can be seen as `Sum` modulo 2. In fact

```
Sum[1, {i, 0}]
(* 0 *)
```

which explains why `Xor[] == False`.

The `And` function can be [regarded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Relation_to_modern_algebra) as the `Product` modulo 2. In fact

```
Product[1, {i, 0}]
(* 1 *)
```

which explains why `And[] == True`.

See also a comment of @DanielLichtblau above, which argues in terms of `Plus` and `Times`.

Comment: (+1) that's a very neat description!!!